# Netbeans IDE does not recognise classes from newly added jar

Tags: java, mongodb, netbeans

I downloaded a mongoldb driver for java from this link:

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver/3.4.2/

In my Netbeans Java Web Application I right-clicked on the Libraries Folder and clicked on "Add JAR/Folder". I navigated to the folder containing the jar-file and added the jar to the Libraries Folder:

[image]

According to the documentation, which you can find here:

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/getting-started/quick-start/

the first step to connect with the database is to write the following line:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
```

I did this and expected the IDE to suggest importing the necessary classes for class "MongoClient" ... However, the IDE does not recognise that the class MongoClient exists and therefore does not suggest an import statement.

I have clean-built the application after adding the mongoldb-file to Libraries - why doesn't the IDE recognise the classes in that jar-file?

Comment: Check out the name of that jar file. What do you suppose is in it? When you did a sanity check inspection of the jar contents what did you see?

Comment: Thank you! I downloaded the wrong jar.

Comment: You've attached the JavaDoc library, not the binrary library

Comment: I know, thanks for your help.